# Call function by using bytesData. (call.value()())

Tags: solidity, calldata

Assume I have two contracts:

```
contract A {
    function test1() public view returns(bool) {
        return false;
    }
}
contract B {
    function testCall(address addr, data) public view returns(bool) {
        return addr.call.value(0)(data);
    }
}
```

Then I call `testCall` in javascript:

```
const a = await A.new()
const b = await B.new()

const aWeb3 = web3.eth.contract(a.abi)
const aInstance = aWeb3.at(a.address)

const testData = aInstance.test1.getData()

const ans = await bInstance.testCall(aInstance.address, testData)

console.log(ans)
```

In this case, `ans` should be `false`, but it returns `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addr.call` type call returns `true` on success and `false` otherwise. To get the actual return value you need to either use the high-level contract interface system or use assembly like

```
assembly{
    let success := call(10000, addr, 0, add(data, 0x20), mload(data), 0, 0x20)
    res := mload(0)
 }
return res
```